# On passing file pointer to my dll function, Debug Assertion Failed comes as Expression: (_osfile(fh) &FOPEN)

Tags: visual-c++

[C/C++]Whenever there is cross build ie. When my main.cpp is of type release and dll as debug OR main.cpp is of type debug and dll as release type, then when I fopen the file in main.cpp and pass its file pointer in the dll function, the file pointer still prints the same address inside the fucntion as was in main.cpp, however if I try to perform any function on it like fflush, fprintf. It throws error (ucrtbase.dll error)/ write.cpp Line 50 error.
I am using Visual studio 19 on Windows 10.

Incase I pass stout instead of my own made file pointer through fopen, then everything on console prints properly without any error.
Also if I do fopen inside my dll, and then operate it is still ok.

Moreover, if my build for both main.cpp as well as DLL is debug-debug OR Release-Release, then also everything works fine while passing the file pointer.

Also, there is no such code for multi threading in my Project.
-Tried HANDLE
-Tried Exception handling for file pointers

- Tried even thread safety using lock Even though there was no such case of multithreading in my cpp project.
  -Installed the latest redustributable ×64 from visual studio site.

Still getting same errors.
However, When I tried (debug dll with release build of main project) by building my dll in debug mode with Properties as Multithreaded dll instead of Multithreaded Debug Dll and then placed inside the release folder for main.cpp project, after running, the Assertion error got removed and the code started to get executed without any obstacle.

I was expecting that anytime the file pointer is passed into any fucntion, and if it prints the same address ie. (Not NULL)and then it should be operable but in this scenario as mentioned above, I got error.

Comment: You generally cannot pass `FILE*` pointers, or most other resources, across module boundaries. It can be made to work if you build all modules so that they link to the same C runtime DLL; but your situation is specifically about modules built with different runtimes. A `FILE*` pointer allocated by one runtime makes no sense to the other. If you intend your modules to be built independently, you must design the interface between them in a way that doesn't involve passing C runtime resources around.